# Git push fail: unable to unlink

Tags: git

I have a problem with all my repos.

When I try to push something for the first time it works but I get the following warning:

```
warning: unable to unlink 'W:/TestRepo.git/./HEAD.lock': Invalid argument
```

After that the file: HEAD.lock remains inside the folder and git wont delete it. From now on I can not push neither do anything else. I will always get the following error:

```
remote: error: cannot lock ref 'HEAD': Unable to create '.../HEAD.lock': File exists.
```

I manually have to delete the "HEAD.lock" file to solve this problem and push 1 more time.

Comment: is your w drive some mounted network share?

Comment: yes it is. It is a mounted network drive on our local linux server. But it worked the last few years like this. I am not sure but maybe the problem exists since I updates to the latest git-version 2.17.1

Comment: I rolled back to git version 2.8.2 and it is working now. There seems to be a bug with the latest version.